# How can I loop a pivot table and know the difference between different subheaders?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried looking at the font but neither font.bold or font.color is different between these lines.

[image]

The pivot table is a very simple three items on the rows and one as values:

[image]

The header text on the left ("Nektarin") is not part of the pivot table, that is a vlookup to get the product name.

So is there any way I can see the difference of the red, green and yellow marked lines with VBA when I loop through the pivot table?

Comment: Is there a requirement to loop through the pivot table, specifically? It might be simpler to analyze the source data. Alternatively, you might try to reformat your pivot to 'classic pivot table layout' which would put your different row values into separate columns.

Comment: I think it will be easier to loop the pivot table. The plan is to generate a webpage or data that can be sent to a webpage of the data. So keeping the format of highest score on top and summarizing will be easier when this is made to web. But I have thought about the classic layout. I was just hoping there was a way that I could keep it nicer looking for humans at the same time. But that is defiantly an option.

Comment: Not sure without seeing your source data, but if it is reliably the case that the 'red' rows are always digits, the 'green' rows are always all in uppercase, and the 'yellow' rows are what's left (mixed lower/uppercase)?

Comment: Otherwise, could use the numbers in the 3rd column ie first row is always a 'red' row and counts as 7 in this case; next row is always a 'green' row and counts as 2; you know you then have 2 yellow rows; as the total from 'green' rows is less than the 'red' row then you know the next row must be green ... and so on

Comment: @JohnM I believe you are right, I can probably use case sensitivity/numeric/other. I was so focused on the formatting that I forgot about the data itself